# Running Single TestFixtures from C# Code

Tags: c#, nunit

I know how to run complete NUnit assemblies from C# Code

```
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(assemblyName);
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty, false, LoggingThreshold.Error);
```

But how can I run single TestFixtures or even Single Tests?

Comment: Never tried it But there's a an overload of run where you can pass in the name or an array of names, where you have TestFiler.Empty, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tony Hopkinson I found the solution.
I just had to create a class inheriting from `TestFilter` and overwrite the `Match` function in there.

```
public class SingleTestFilter : TestFilter
{
    private string testName;

    public SingleTestFilter(string TestName)
    {
        testName = TestName;
    }


    public override bool Match(ITest test)
    {
        return test.TestName.Name.Equals(testName);
    }
}
```

And then call the `remoteTestRunner.Run` with it as parameter.

```
remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), new SingleTestFilter("MyTest"), false, LoggingThreshold.Error);
```